# AKS AAD Pod Identity Throwing Forbidden (403)

Tags: azure-aks

### [SOLVED] See my answer below.

So I am trying to integrate KeyVault with an existing AKS Cluster using AAD Pod Identity.

I have closely followed the [documentation for integrating it into the cluster](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity), but for some reason I am getting a 403 when trying to access the key vault from the pod that has the `aadboundidentity`.

My cluster has RBAC, so I have used the yaml from the AAD Pod Github for RBAC.

Here is what my `aadpodidentity.yml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  name: aks-kv-identity
spec:
  type: 0
  ResourceID: <full-resource-id-of-managed-id>
  ClientID: <client-id-of-aks-cluster-sp>
```

My `aadpodidentitybinding.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: azure-identity-binding
spec:
  AzureIdentity: aks-kv-identity
  Selector: kv_selector
```

The pod's yaml that I'd like to bind to:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: data-access
  labels: 
    app: data-access
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: data-access
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: data-access
        aadpodidbinding: kv_selector
    spec:
      containers:  
      - name: data-access
        image: data-access:2020.02.22.0121
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

My AKS SP also has the 'Reader' Role assigned to the Key Vault

Comment: Suggest you add an answer to display the solution for your issue if you solved it, not just edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue.

This is how I solved it:

1. In the `aadpodidentitybinding.yml` I was using the clientId of the AKS
   SP when I **needed to use the Client ID of the Managed Identity.**
2. I needed to ensure that my Managed Identity had the Reader role in my
   Resource Group
3. I needed to assign the correct policies to the managed identity in
   the Key Vault

[This article](https://dev.to/cmendibl3/aks-read-azure-key-vault-secrets-using-aad-pod-identity-2f3i) was actually super helpful. I just followed the steps here, and it worked perfectly.

Note: I added my Managed Identity in the Resource group that had the AKS cluster, not the Resource Group of the resources for the AKS cluster (i.e the one that starts with MC_).